# How to copy files from testdrive

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk, photorec

I had win 10 and I installed ubuntu. During the process I formatted the entire hard drive. Then I used testdisk on live usb. I can explore files in it but cant figure out how to copy and recover them.

Comment: okay, where are the files right now, the USB?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that specific software, but in general you can't store files on the partition you use for a Linux live USB.  And you can't store files on the disk you are recovering from either, for hopefully obvious reasons.  I *think* you just need to plug in another external drive.

Comment: If you meant `testdisk` see [my answer in section "copy single files"](http://askubuntu.com/a/286206/3940).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer at this link has really good information https://askubuntu.com/a/286206/3940.

To directly answer your question. Use another USB device or pendrive to copy the files to. If you don't have another USB device or pendrive, you can also copy to a writable DVD or CD. An external hard drive would be great.

Remember, don't copy any files to the old windows 10 drive and do not set testdisk to send results of the scans to the windows 10 drive either!